# How to print a triangle using for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

I need some help trying to solve this, right now it keeps printing vertically only

[image: I need it to come out as]

```
height = int(input("Height of triangle: "))
for x in range(height):
   for y in range(height):
     print("#",end = '')
     print()
```

Comment: `for y in range(x)` will give you dynamic row-lengths!

Comment: Those are not very good triangles. Are you sure you don't want the vertices at the top and at the lower right?

Comment: I tried for y in range(x) it works but do you know how I could get the space in the middle of the triangles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution, it involves the use an of accumulator:

```
height = int(input("Height of triangle: "))
count = 0

for i in range(height-1):
    print('#' + ' '*count + '#')
    count += 1

print('#'*height)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
height = 6

for rowIndex in xrange(height-1):
    row = [' ']*height            # yields array of size height
    row[0] = row[rowIndex+1] = '#'
    print (''.join(row))    # This makes string from array
print ('#'*height)          # Print lower side of triangle
```

You can also remove "+1" on line 5 to get more "edgy" triangles.