# How to print a shape in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a shape with Python using the console output.

My code for printing  shape with no spaces is as

```
tri=int(input("enter size : "))
```

Which results in the output

```
enter size : 6                                                                                                                            
******                                                                                                                                    
*****                                                                                                                                     
****                                                                                                                                      
***                                                                                                                                       
**                                                                                                                                        
*
```

However, the shape should look like this

```
******
*   *
*  *
* *
*
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When posting your code make sure that someone else can run it easily. Also try to make your description as clear as possible – which is already almost the case. I'll make few edits to your question to improve it.

Comment: If there are going to be more than 2 `*` in a line, and it's not the first `*` line, then only print the first and last `*`.

Comment: Also, **before asking a question, try to search SO first**. There are already a lot of "How to do a triangle in X" questions out there. In particular, have a look at [How to print a triangle using for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726898/how-to-print-a-triangle-using-for-loops) and try to adapt it to your needs. ___So this also a possible duplicate for that existing question ;)___

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print a triangle using for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37726898/how-to-print-a-triangle-using-for-loops)

Comment: What is the expected output for `tri = 3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is your solution :)

```
n=int(input("enter size : "))
for row in range(0,n):
    for col in range(0,n):
        if row == 0 or col == 0 or row==n-col-1:
            print("*", end="")
        else:
            print(end=" ")
    print()
```

example input:

```
enter size : 6
******
*   *
*  *
* *
**
*
```